# How to detect C# control name changed?

Tags: c#, controls, composite-controls

I created a composite control using C# Windows Forms Control Library, when I use the new control in a test program, I want to find a way to detect when did the name of new control changed at design time, what should I do?

Comment: Are you talking about a composite Control based on UserControl? Is the the UserControl's Name Property you want to react on?

Comment: Yes, I want to detect it at design time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IComponentChangeService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in `System.ComponentModel.Design`) like in this example:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler NameChanged;
    protected virtual void OnNameChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = NameChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        IComponentChangeService changeService = (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
        if (changeService == null) return; // not provided at runtime, only design mode

        changeService.ComponentChanged -= OnComponentChanged; // to avoid multiple subscriptions
        changeService.ComponentChanged += OnComponentChanged;
    }

    private void OnComponentChanged(object sender, ComponentChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Component == this && e.Member.Name == "Name")
            OnNameChanged();            
    }
}
```

This service is only provided in design mode, not at runtime.
I unsubscribe and subscribe again to the `ComponentChanged` event (to avoid multiple subscriptions).

In the event handler `OnComponentChanged` I check if my name has changed and raise the `NameChanged` event.

Comment: The code you provide are very useful, but I got another problem. How to get the name I typed in the properties window? I use the `this.Name` to get the name, but what I get is "MyControl" not the word I typed in the properties window

Comment: @TwenteMaster `this.Name` actually works fine for me (as long as `this` is really the correct instance, please check). I think I'd need to see more code, but it sounds like that would rather be a new question.

Comment: I forgot to tell you one more information, In my code, `MyControl` is inherited from `UserControl`, not `Control`, is this the problem with? If it is, what should I do? I don't want to change the inheritance relationship

Comment: @TwenteMaster There is no difference, it works with `UserControl` as well. I tried it with a `MessageBox.Show(this.Name)` in my `OnNameChanged` and when I set the `(Name)` property in designer, it shows a `MessageBox` with the correct changed value.

Comment: I found the reason, it's other code change the name, I have solved it. many thanks for your help

Comment: I also saw that `this.Name` and `Name` give what TwenteMaster observed, which is the class name of the control--not the expected property sheet name. TwenteMaster never revealed how the problem was solved... I recommend using `Site.Name` instead--it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event "OnNameChanged" and the Name-Property itself is not virtual and therefore not overrideable... I'm afraid, that there is no sure way...

Some suggestions:

- Define your own Name-Property with "new", but inherited classes will not automatically overtake this and - even worse - casts to Control and usage of Control.Name will just work around your property...
- Define a virtual "MyName"-Property and use this only to write through onto the Control's Name-Property. Still a call on Control.Name will fly by, but at least you can enforce the usage of MyName...
- Puffer the Name within your constructor and define a Timer to look regularely if something has changed

Alltogether I must admit, that I would not use any of those... I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but I'd try to find a different approach to reach this goal...

Answer (score -1):

```
public MyControl : UserControl
{
     public new string Name 
     {
         get  { return base.Name; }

         set  
         {
            base.Name = value;

            // handle the name change here....
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: That won't work. If you call `((UserControl)myControl).Name = "..."` only the base property is invoked.